# day.js timezone plugin method produce an invalid Date

Tags: angular, typescript, dayjs

I used a long time, dayjs in an angular project, to convert timestamps in a rest response from UTC to localtime. After my last update, it does not work anymore. It is not the first problem with dayjs, so I write a utility class to convert the timestamps at a central place. But it fails in Angular 12, 14 and also in a typescript test project on stackblitz. I detect a malfunction in the tz function of dayjs, because if I call the isValid function of the result is false.

tl;dr
The conversion of a dayjs date to another timezone in typescript returns an invalid date:

```
dayjs.utc(time).tz('America/New_York').isValid()
```

is false. I prepared a small [test project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-f3xd1n?file=time-util.ts) on stackblitz. Here is the TimeUtil class:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone';
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc';

dayjs.extend(timezone);
dayjs.extend(utc);


export class TimeUtil {
  public timeZoneLocal: string = dayjs.tz.guess();

  public debug(time: dayjs.Dayjs): Date {

    console.log('Debug Information:');
    console.log('time:', time);
    console.log('utc:', dayjs.utc(time));
    console.log('tz:', dayjs.utc(time).tz('America/New_York'));
    console.log('time valid? ', time.isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    console.log('utc valid? ', dayjs.utc(time).isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    console.log('tz valid? ', dayjs.utc(time).tz('America/New_York').isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')

    return dayjs.utc(time).tz('America/New_York').toDate();
  }

  public toLocal(time: dayjs.Dayjs): Date {
    return dayjs(time).tz(this.timeZoneLocal).toDate();
  }
}
```

The toLocal Method always returns null. To find the error, I wrote a debug method. The output of the debug method is:

```
Debug Information:
time: 2023-01-10T05:34:00.000Z
utc: 2023-01-10T05:34:00.000Z
tz: null
time valid? Yes
utc valid? Yes
tz valid? No
```

I activated `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

How I got my toLocal method working?

Is there another easy way to parse an utc iso datestring and convert him to a local date?

It appears to be an OS issue as Firefox, Chrome and Intellij are affected. On my work PC and on my Android Tablet everything works fine.

Comment: Your test project console shows a non-null tz value, and "tz valid? Yes"

Comment: I use Firefox 102.6.0esr and Chromium 108.0.5359.124 on Gentoo Linux and it returns "tz valid? No" there. It fails also in Intellij, when I debug the method in Typescript. On my Android Tablet it I got "tz valid? Yes". I updated also my Linux two weeks ago. Perhaps this is the cause.

Comment: Hum nasty indeed if it depends on the OS! :-S What does `dayjs.tz.guess()` give? I suspect an issue detecting the local timezone on some environments.

Comment: The time zone is `Europe/Berlin`.

Comment: When I unfold the `time: dayjs.Dayjs` argument in the intellij debugger, I saw a member of time named `$d` of type `Date` with a localized content of `$d = Tue Jan 10 2023 06:34:00 GMT +0100 Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit {}`

Comment: Try `dayjs.utc(time).local().tz('America/New_York')`

Comment: It cause also in an invalid Date.  I think it is this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=13490) but I'm not shure. `new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US"))` fails in Firefox and Chromium. I will update my Gentoo Linux and will ask in the Gentoo forum.

Comment: I found a way to do without dayjs/timezone as the component in my Angular webapp does this conversion as well - whether on gentoo or android. Out of interest, I'll test again in a few months to see if the problem still exists on Gentoo.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

I'm adding my updated answer here, and leaving the original below with some original details

### Background

As reported on a [chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=13494) the latest version of International Components for Unicode (ICU) causes `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` to use a unicode `U+202F` character instead of an ascii space character.

That causes code like this to fail with an `Invalid Date` error

```
new Date((new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US'))
```

Unfortunately, `dayjs` uses [that pattern](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/9c20e77caf7b1b5eccf418175203b198d4e29535/src/plugin/timezone/index.js#L98) in the timezone plugin (even though it's mostly considered an anti-pattern).

```
const target = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timezone })
const diff = Math.round((date - new Date(target)) / 1000 / 60)
```

This issue is [fixed](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/45573) in Node 19 and backported to Node 18.13 (LTS). On older versions of Node, it only affects systems with an updated version of the ICU library.

There are similar fixes from [chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/2ada52cffbff11074abfaac18938bf02d85454f5), [Mozilla](https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D160188) and [WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/1dc01f753d89a85ee19df8e8bd75f4aece80c594) for their respective browsers.

### Possible fixes

1. Patch `dayjs` (e.g. via `yarn patch` https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch) and replace the unicode character with a string before it gets re-parsed.

```
const target = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timezone }).replace(/[\u202f]/, " ")
```

2. Upgrade your browser to a version with the fix implemented.

## Original below

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I believe I'm seeing the same behavior in a node project, and this is the only mention I've been able to find about it online. This started happening last week some time (I started noticing test failures on Jan 20)

### Environment

M1 Macbook Air on MacOS 12.5.1 (Monterey)

dayjs version `1.10.7` (hasn't been upgraded in 14 months)

node version `16.19.0`

### Behavior

I have essentially the same repro as you that I'm running via `jest` (this first popped up for me as local tests failures). Note that I'm getting local time via `dayjs()` so there's definitely no parsing issue here.

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs"
import timezone from "dayjs/plugin/timezone"
import utc from "dayjs/plugin/utc"

dayjs.extend(timezone)
dayjs.extend(utc)

export class TimeUtil {
  public debug(time = dayjs()) {
    console.log('Debug Information:')
    console.log('time:', time.format())
    console.log('utc:', time.utc().format())
    console.log('tz:', time.tz('America/New_York').format())
    console.log('time valid? ', time.isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    console.log('utc valid? ', time.utc().isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')
    console.log('tz valid? ', time.tz('America/New_York').isValid() ? 'Yes' : 'No')
  }
}
```

The output shows the timezone dayjs object is invalid

```
$ yarn test tztest

Debug Information:
time: 2023-01-24T12:00:20-08:00
utc: 2023-01-24T20:00:20Z
tz: Invalid Date
time valid?  Yes
utc valid?  Yes
tz valid?  No
```

### Docker workaround (not viable long-term)

The failure behavior does not occur in a `node:16.19.0` docker container with the exact same source mounted as a volume.

```
version: '2'
services:
  api-on-node:
    image: node:16.19.0
    container_name: api-on-node
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    tty: true
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

```
$ docker exec -it api-on-node yarn test tztest

Debug Information:
time: 2023-01-24T12:00:21-08:00
utc: 2023-01-24T20:00:21Z
tz: 2023-01-24T15:00:21-05:00
time valid?  Yes
utc valid?  Yes
tz valid?  Yes
```

So this does seem to be very environment specific. And it is new behavior, although I haven't been able to figure out what changed to cause the new behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me a ton of time

Comment: Recommend this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz over dayjs for handling timezone stuff